# How can I run osascript with python on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, automation, embed, osascript

How can you add login item in system preferences with python using osascript or any other method on macos,
Is this process right?
**subprocess.call("osascript -e add login items to System Preferences {Path: "/home"; value: hidden} at end, shell=True").**

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you need help on how to call a process in Python, how to use osascript, or what exactly?

Comment: Hello, I would like to know whether it is possible to use osascript with python, and whether my way of doing it is right or wrong, if wrong what could be the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `osascript` with **Python**, but you will need to use the proper command syntaxes for both.  I'm not sure where you came up with that script, but AppleScript terms can be found in an application's scripting dictionary (if it has one), in this case the **Login Items Suite** from **System Events**.

Since AppleScript only uses double quotes, using `subprocess.call` with a list of strings for the arguments can avoid a lot of quote escaping, and would be something like :

```
import subprocess

def add_login_item(item_name, item_path):
   script = ('tell application "System Events" to make new login item at end of login items with properties {name:"%s", path:"%s", hidden:false}' % (item_name, item_path))
   subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', script])

add_login_item('Item Name', '/full/path/to/whatever.app')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, also can we add path in a different variable and then add it to subprocess.call.

Comment: @Blackmoon - String interpolation runs into issues with the characters used, so to keep with avoiding a lot of escaping, you can use a string template or just add the string pieces and variables together.

Comment: Actually, percent interpolation can also be used, but `format` and `f` strings use curly braces, which AppleScript also uses, so some escaping would need to be done for those.  I’ve edited my answer to include a function that uses interpolation.

Comment: Can we not just cancatenate with + operator.

Comment: @Blackmoon - Yes, I mentioned that in my earlier comment.